# What is the equivalent of onBackPressed() for overriding and taking control of the Recent Apps button on Android?

Tags: java, android

This is the method to access Android's Back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something on back.
return;
}
```

I want to do something similar for the Recent Apps button (the right most one)

Comment: `Recent Apps button`?? what is that

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin The highlighted button here: http://www.android.com/images/ics/tasks-sm.png

Comment: I am not sure Android OS allows you to override those features; I tried it before but was not successful.

Comment: You can't override that per-app, but you can to it globally, by writing your own launcher, ie. taking over the Home button and so on.

Comment: If you're interested, there is a button u can add (not sure if it is samsung device exlusive though) that can be added. It is usually used by apps to open settings and stuff. I have no idea what it is called though, sry.

Answer (score 0):

You can really change the functionality of the `AppButton` programatically except if you are creating your own custom launcher but you can still detect if the **AppButton** is pressed in your app.

**sample:**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if(!hasFocus)
        Log.d("APP BUTTON", "APP BUTTON");
}
```